# Simplest framework for converting python app into webapp?

Tags: python, django

I have a small python app that I would like to convert into a webapp. I have look at some frameworks out there such as django.

I need some suggestions on a very simple framework. All my webapp will have is a textbox and two buttons.

Comment: take a look at [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) and [`werkzeug`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Nemoden's comment should be an answer. Also try [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/) or just plain [`WSGI`](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), great for simple webapps. Example code from their website:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 2):

**CherryPy** would serve you the best if you are looking for a minimalist one.

Answer (score 1):

It small framework for webapp [Flask framewrok](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for bottle.

Nevertheless, consider that the scope usually grows when developing web apps and that text box and those 2 buttons will later on need: templates, lots of routes, maybe translations, etc. So, always consider using something that would allow you to move into some powerful framework such as web2py or Django.